# In Windows 7 _ Is It Possible to widen the arrow button next to Switch Off button on Start Menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-x64, startmenu

In Windows 7 _ Is It Possible to widen the arrow button next to Switch Off button on Start Menu?

It would be more ergonomic to aim for a wide button with mouse click

e. g.: via some new Registry Database entry, or something else?

Thank you

https://imgur.com/a/uvBTAdG

I could only guess ... but no idea so far sadly how to do that